# How to display markers in groundOverlay map?

Tags: api, google-maps, overlay, google-maps-markers

I can manage to display my image overlay on the map. But a new problem occurs - I can't add a marker on it. I googled it for a while but no luck. Tried to search and mimic the example on documentation and nothing appears to be right.

Here's my code :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
      var newark = new google.maps.LatLng(xx.xxxxx,xx.xxxxx);
      var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
          new google.maps.LatLng(xx.xxxxx,xx.xxxxx),//SW
          new google.maps.LatLng(xx.xxxxx,xx.xxxxx)//NE
        );

      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 20,
        center: newark,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

      var oldmap = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
          'images/floor_plan_trans_rotated.gif',
          imageBounds);
      oldmap.setMap(map);
    }

    /*markers*/
      var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
          '<div id="siteNotice">'+
          '</div>'+
          '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
          '<div id="bodyContent">'+
          '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
          'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
          'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
          'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+

</p>'+
      '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
      'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
      '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
      maxWidth: 400
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: newark,
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}

/*markers*/
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

For the code above. The map will not display unless I delete those lines between /*markers*/.

Please suggest.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

isn't there an extra } just above the first /*markers*/ on this code ?  or maybe i'm just sleepy....

i'm doing something similar and it is working, with groundOverlay and marker on the same map

Comment: This is maybe comment worthy, but not an answer.

Comment: To critique or request clarification from OP please add a comment (not an answer :)).

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things are misplaced in your code.

1. Missing single quote (') before </p>
2. Closing the initialize function brace way earlier (})

Rest all seems to be fine. I corrected these and here is the complete code.

```
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var newark = new google.maps.LatLng(xx.xxxxx,xx.xxxxx);
        var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(xx.xxxxx,xx.xxxxx),//SW
            new google.maps.LatLng(xx.xxxxx,xx.xxxxx)//NE
        );

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 18,
            center: newark,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var oldmap = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
            'images/floor_plan_trans_rotated.gif', imageBounds);
        oldmap.setMap(map);

        /*markers*/
        var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
            '<div id="siteNotice">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
            '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
            'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
            'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
            'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
            '</p>'+
            '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
            'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
            '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString,
            maxWidth: 400
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: newark,
            map: map,
            title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    }

    /*markers*/
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```